# shiny dt bookmarking state

Tags: r, shiny, bookmarks, dt

Dear R Shiny community,

I am trying to create a bookmarking state for Shiny app where I render table with DT package. For example, in the app pasted below I want to type some text in the search field which subsets data and bookmark that state, i.e. get a URL that I can share. Another user can use the URL and see the same subset of the table without a need to type the text again into the search field. With the code below I was expecting to see the "Bookmark" button with the option 1 code or a dynamic URL with option 2, but unfortunately it does not work as expected. Does anyone know how to make a bookmarking state when rendering a table with DT?

Here is the reproducible code:

Option 1

```
library(shiny)

ui <- function(request) {
    fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl'))
}

server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
        iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

Option 2

```
library(shiny)

ui <- function(request) {
    fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl'))
}

server = function(input, output) {
    observe({
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
        iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
    )
    })
    onBookmarked(function(url) {
        updateQueryString(url)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

Thank you so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 4):

Based on the following discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/DvWhqwZ8OKw I was able to find an answer.

I was able to modify the option 1 and here is the minimal reproducible app that works. Just type a string in a global search field, click on the bookmark button on the bottom, copy the url and share.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- function(request) {
 fluidPage(
 DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')
 , bookmarkButton(label = "Bookmark", title = "Link to this view")

 )
}

server = function(input, output) {

 # exclude some values query variables from url
 setBookmarkExclude(names = c("resTable_rows_all",
 "resTable_cell_clicked"))

 # proxy for table manipulations
 tbl_proxy <- dataTableProxy("tbl")

 # restore table selection and search
 onRestored(function(state) {

 # req(state$input$resTable_search)
 DT::updateSearch(tbl_proxy, 
 keywords = list(global = state$input$tbl_search))
 })

 output$tbl <- renderDataTable(iris)

}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```